# telegram бот (pyTelegramBotAPI) - проверка на наличие username, при отсутствии - возвращать first_name

Tags: python, telegram-bot

есть кусок кода:

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True, content_types=['sticker'])
def handle_sticker(message):
    bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     text=("@{!s}, " + strings_data.get(get_language(message.from_user.language_code)).get("withoutstickers")).format(bot.get_chat_member(message.chat.id, message.from_user.id).user.username))
```

пояснение - при получении стикера бот удаляет его и отправляет сообщение типа '@username, без стикеров.' но бывают пользователи без username и тогда он обращается '@None'.

необходимо сделать проверку на наличие username, а при его отсутствии - возвращать first_name. я знаю как выцепить сам username и first_name
`bot.get_chat_member(message.chat.id, message.from_user.id).user.username` (или `user.first_name`)

но как приделать проверку я не знаю. можете помочь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

после пары часов пришёл к такому решению. может и не лучшее, но работает так как мне нужно.

создаём функцию (поправьте, если это что-то другое), которая проверяет, есть ли username

```
# получение username, если пусто - возвращает first_name
def get_username(message):
    usr = bot.get_chat_member(message.chat.id, message.from_user.id)
    if not usr.user.username:
        return usr.user.first_name
    else:
        return usr.user.username
```

далее модифицируем хендлер, удаляющий сообщения со стикерами

```
    # удаление стикеров
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True, content_types=['sticker'])
def handle_sticker(message):
    # sticker_id = bot.get_file(message.sticker.file_id)
    bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
    stickertext = (strings_data.get(get_language(message.from_user.language_code)).get("withoutstickers"))
    if get_username(message) == bot.get_chat_member(message.chat.id, message.from_user.id).user.username:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 
                         text=("@{!s}, " + stickertext).format(get_username(message)))
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 
                         text=("{!s}, " + stickertext).format(get_username(message)))
```

вы видите, что там появилась конструкция `if-else`, значения в которой отличаются одним символом. сделано это было для того, чтобы при упоминании по `first_name` не было знака `@` в начале, так как мог упомянутся вообще левый человек, а по `first_name` всё равно нет упоминания, это обычный текст. хотя можно по `user.id` попытаться сделать, но если это кому-то нужно, он сам доделает.